# Using iPhone 6s or iPhone 6s plus attachments with an iPhone 5/iPhone 5s/iPhone SE

Tags: iphone, case

There are some nice lens attachments for the iPhone 6s and iPhone 6s plus chassis. Are there adapters or cases that will permit the iPhone5/iPhone 5s/iPhone SE chassis to make use of these attachments?

To be very clear:

- By "adapter" I mean plastic or foam jiggy-bits that would fit, alongside the iPhone 5/iPhone SE inside an iPhone 6s or iPhone 6s plus case.
- By "cases" I mean an external covering into which the phone fits.

Comment: Even if there were, the optics wouldn't match.

Comment: @Tetsujin The optics in question are adjustable.

Comment: Adjustable how? Any lens needs to 'know' the actual distance to sensor, i.e., the focal plane, otherwise it will either mis-focus or be unable to reach infinity.

Comment: That's right @Tetsujin, the lens actually has a mechanism to adjust that distance. At any rate, your comments are veering away from my question.